# How to write a function that passes NULL to ggplot without getting aesthetics error

Tags: r, ggplot2, null, aesthetics

I am trying to write a function that creates plots and ran into an error that I don't understand.  Here is a simplified example.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library (ggplot2)
# Sample data
xdata = 0:20
ydata = 20:40
dat <- data.frame(xdata, ydata)

# This works
line_p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = xdata, y = ydata, group = NULL, color = NULL)) + geom_line()
line_p
```

I expected the following to work, but get an aesthetics error, but in this case the x and y variables are the same length.  The issues seems to be having a default value of NULL for group and color.  I tried explicitly passing NULL as well with aes_group and aes_color as function variables but this also did not work.

```
# Using a function doesn't work:

# create function
line_function <- function(mydata     = dat,
                          xinput     = x,
                          yinput     = y,
                          aes_group  = NULL,
                          aes_color  = NULL,
                          ...) {

  lineplot <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = xinput, y = yinput, group = aes_group, color = aes_color)) + geom_line()
}


# test the function
line_test_p <- line_function(
  mydata = dat,
  xinput = xdata,
  yinput = ydata
)

line_test_p
```

Testing with explicit inputs

```
# test the function again with explicit NULL inputs

line_test2_p <- line_function(
  mydata    = dat,
  xinput    = xdata,
  yinput    = ydata,
  aes_group = NULL,
  aes_color = NULL
)

line_test2_p
```

Is it not possible to write a generic function where ggplot will interpret the NULL values as in the example that works without a function, or am I missing something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you should check out [`aes_string`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html) for creating aesthetic mappings programmatically. It allows you to create aesthetic mappings using the names of variables stored strings. That way, it's easy to pass column names as arguments to a function and create the corresponding plot.

The following version of your function works for me:

```
# create function
line_function <- function(mydata     = dat,
                          xinput     = "x", # note the defaults are
                          yinput     = "y", # strings here
                          aes_group  = NULL,
                          aes_color  = NULL,
                          ...) {

  ggplot(mydata, # this should be the argument, not the global variable dat
         # now we create the aes binding with aes_string
         aes_string(x = xinput,
                    y = yinput,
                    group = aes_group,
                    color = aes_color)) +
    geom_line()
}
```

And now you can use the function to create your examples:

```
# test the function
line_test_p <- line_function(
  mydata = dat,
  xinput = "xdata", # note the strings
  yinput = "ydata"
)

# test the function again with explicit NULL inputs
line_test2_p <- line_function(mydata    = dat,
                              xinput    = "xdata", # and strings here
                              yinput    = "ydata",
                              aes_group = NULL,
                              aes_color = NULL)
```

And things should work out for you. Again, do check out the [documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html), because there are different ways you can accomplish this, and you may prefer different ways for different purposes or preferences.

Comment: Andrew, that's it, thanks.  The simplest change after reading the documentation was to change the lineplot line to: **lineplot <- ggplot(mydata, aes_(x = xinput, y = yinput, group = aes_group, color = aes_color)) + geom_line()**  I also should have used **mydata** as the variable in the function as you mentioned, not **dat**